# bazel - how do I package a specific file from a build target files (cc_library)

Tags: shared-libraries, static-libraries, bazel

I am new to bazel and have some question:

I have defined a library xxx like this:

```
cc_library(
    name = "xxx",
    srcs = glob(["lib/*.c"]),
    hdrs = glob(["include/*.h"]),
    copts = ["-Iinclude -Werror"],
)
```

Using pkg_tar, I saw that it produces a target files :xxx which have the .so and the .a :

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/pkg:pkg.bzl", "pkg_tar")

pkg_tar(
    name = "libxxx",
    package_dir = "/usr/lib/",
    srcs = [":xxx"],
    mode = "0644",
)
```

I want to get only the static library .a, how do I do, for the moment, I found only this solution:

```
pkg_tar(
    name = "libxxx-static",
    package_dir = "/usr/lib/",
    srcs = [":xxx"],
    # FIXME
    strip_prefix = "libxxx.so",
    mode = "0644",
)
```

How do I get only one file in target files ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `linkstatic` field of [cc_library()](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.linkstatic),

> The linkstatic attribute has a different meaning if used on a cc_library() rule. For a C++ library, linkstatic=True indicates that only static linking is allowed, so no .so will be produced. linkstatic=False does not prevent static libraries from being created. The attribute is meant to control the creation of dynamic libraries.

Like so:

```
cc_library(
    name = "xxx",
    srcs = glob(["lib/*.c"]),
    hdrs = glob(["include/*.h"]),
    copts = ["-Iinclude -Werror"],
    linkstatic = True,
)
```